On $\prod_p\frac{p^3 - 2p + 1}{p^3}$
Is there a way to express the product
$$\prod_p\left(\frac{p^3 - 2p + 1}{p^3}\right),$$
where the product is taken over all primes $p$? This product came up in the study of the sum
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \le x}\varphi(n)^2 &= \sum_{d \le n}f(d)\sum_{e \le n/d}n^2 \\
&\approx \frac{n^3}3\sum_{d \le n}\frac{f(d)}{d^3} \\
&\approx \frac{n^3}3\sum_{d \ge 1}\frac{f(d)}{d^3} \\
&\approx \frac{n^3}3\prod_p\left(1+\frac{f(p)}{p^3}\right),
\end{align*}$$
where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient and $f$ is a multiplicative function with $f(1) = 1$, $f(p) = -2p + 1$, and $f(p^k) = 0$ for $k \ge 2$.

Search 'carefree constant' in this Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product, or here - https://oeis.org/A065464

Look at that.
